# Adding strings to list of objects

Tags: java

```
class Analyze_bs implements Analyzable {
    protected String content;
    protected List<Word> words;
    protected String filePath;
    protected int line;

    @Override
    public void loadContent(String content, Set<Character> punctuationSet) throws AnalyzableException {
        if(content != null || punctuationSet != null) {
            throw new AnalyzableException("bad data foo");
        }
        words = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int pos = 0; pos < content.length(); pos++){
        }
    }
```

This method is supposed to take the input content and load it into the program through the words list. I have tried using the `list = array.Select().ToList();` method that I found in another thread by using first a String array(didn't work) and then a char array(also didn't work, got like 4 errors in each one), but neither worked out for me as I got errors like `can't convert from int to char/string.`

```
char [] wordss;
if(content != null || punctuationSet != null) {
    throw new AnalyzableException("bad data foo");
}
words = new ArrayList<>();
for(int pos = 0; pos < content.length(); pos++){
    wordss[pos] = content.charAt(pos);
    words = wordss.Select(pos => new Word { text = pos}).ToList();
}
```

This is how I tried to implement method I found.

```
public Word(String text, int position, int length, int line, int positionInLine) {
    this.text = text;
    this.position = position;
    this.length = length;
    this.line = line;
    this.positionInLine = positionInLine;
}
```

This is the constructor for the objects that occupy the "words" list.

Is there a better way of doing this or what am I missing?

Comment: lambda symbol in java is `->`, alse `charAt` returns index of character found or -1

Comment: That fixed one issue, but now I'm getting an error that says it expects "(" at the end  of   " = pos}" and when I do add another parentheses there it just leads to more errors which gets me thinking i must have typed something else wrong?

Comment: It looks like you're looking at C# examples and trying to apply them to Java. They're different languages.

Comment: `new Word { text = pos}` is C# syntax, do `new Word(...provide arguments here)` in java to directly call the constructor